# CUDA: optimizing data transfer when input arguments are constant during program execution

Tags: cuda

For illustrative purposes, let

`__device__ void distance(char *s1, char* s2)`

be the device function, which is run over across several blocks and threads `compute<<<1024,256>>>(s1, s2, s3)`.

We can assume `char *s1` and `char *s2` are generated prior to issuing CUDA instructions, and that they are constant throughout execution of all kernels. Is there a way to allocate `s1` and `s1` such that transferring them to all threads is optimized?  Is using `__const__` declaration an appropriate way to optimize data data transfer?

I'm using a device with compute capability 8.0+.

Comment: constant memory has a limit of 64kb, so unless your s1 and s2 are small, it is unlikely to be much use to you

Comment: @talonmies I only meant sharing the pointers themselves, so 16 bytes only.

Comment: All kernel arguments are automagically passed in constant memory so the optimal solution is to do exactly nothing

Comment: See the linked duplicate for a more elaborate answer covering simple arguments like pointers as well as passing structs by value

Comment: thanks, my experiments also showed that adding `__constant__` didn't improve the results, so I was wondering if there's anything else to do.